# Type error using OpenCV to display a rectangle generated from a JSON file

Tags: python, json, opencv

I am trying to use the python code from this link

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/01/16/generating-movie-barcodes-with-opencv-and-python/

for a personal project (I want to make a movie poster out of the barcode). When running the visualization script however I get the following error:

```
D:\movie-barcode>py visualize_barcode.py --avgs output/the_dark_knight_trailer.json --barcode output/test.png --barcode-width 2
[17 87 11]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "visualize_barcode.py", line 37, in <module>
    args["height"]), avg, -1)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

As far as I can tell the json file this script is going through is correct, and i can't determine why the code is not working (one would think it would be working if the person who created it published it after all). Is it maybe an issue with my python version? I'm not sure, i have it up to date.

Here is the code for the visualization script:

```
# USAGE
# python visualize_barcode.py --avgs output/jurassic_park_trailer.json --barcode output/jurassic_park_trailer.png --barcode-width 5

# import the necessary packages
import numpy as np
import argparse
import json
import cv2

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-a", "--avgs", required=True,
    help="path to averages JSON file")
ap.add_argument("-b", "--barcode", required=True,
    help="path to output barcode visualization image")
ap.add_argument("-t", "--height", type=int, default=250,
    help="height of output barcode image")
ap.add_argument("-w", "--barcode-width", type=int, default=1,
    help="width of each bar in output image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load the averages file and convert it to a NumPy array
avgs = json.loads(open(args["avgs"]).read())
avgs = np.array(avgs, dtype="int")

# grab the individual bar width and allocate memory for
# the barcode visualization
bw = args["barcode_width"]
barcode = np.zeros((args["height"], len(avgs) * bw, 3),
    dtype="uint8")

# loop over the averages and create a single 'bar' for
# each frame average in the list
for (i, avg) in enumerate(avgs):
    cv2.rectangle(barcode, (i * bw, 0), ((i + 1) * bw,
        args["height"]), avg, -1)

# write the video barcode visualization to file and then
# display it to our screen
cv2.imwrite(args["barcode"], barcode)
cv2.imshow("Barcode", barcode)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Any help with figuring this out would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Seems like a good time to do some debugging... inspect all the values of the input parameters of the function call that fails. Do they match the requirements specified in the documentation?

Comment: they include some examples of inputs as well as the files to match them and i copied them exactly, the same error still occurs

Answer (score 0):

Try changing dtype in the numpy array to "float":

```
    avgs = np.array(avgs, dtype="float")
```

I used the same code and got the same error message, and this solved it for me!